# Handeling the shape of a specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I  have [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) that I'm interested only in the values of the last column.

```
np.shape(dataframe.iloc[:,:])  # the output is (2190,460)
# Now here is the shape of one cell in the last column 

np.shape(dataframe.iloc[0,-1]) # the output is ( 20,)

dataframe.iloc[0,-1] # the output [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My question is how can get this column saved in the following shape : `(2190, 20)`
since running:

```
np.shape(dataframe.iloc[:,-1]) # the output (2190,)
```

And this shape is causing me a huge problems

**Solution using a loop:**

```
Test_Labels = []
for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    Test_Labels.append(dataframe.iloc[i,-1])
np.shape(Test_Labels)
```

If someone can solve it using a pandas function, will be glad to see it.

Comment: `dataframe[dataframe.columns[-1]]`

Comment: @StephenRauch did you test that ?

Comment: On a small (2x2) dataframe.

Comment: I've tested it here couldn't see a difference !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last column from a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) like:

**Code:**

```
df[df.columns[-1]]
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [dt.datetime(2017, 1, 3),
                         dt.datetime(2017, 2, 4),
                         dt.datetime(2017, 3, 5)],
                   "b": [[2, 4], [6, 8], [10, 12]]})

print(df)
print(df[df.columns[-1]])
```

**Results:**

```
           a         b
0 2017-01-03    [2, 4]
1 2017-02-04    [6, 8]
2 2017-03-05  [10, 12]

0      [2, 4]
1      [6, 8]
2    [10, 12]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

**But I need the result to be an array of arrays not lists**

If you need to convert the *array of lists*, to an *array of arrays*, then cast the whole to a `numpy.array`, numpy will reach in and convert the inner lists to arrays.

```
last_col = np.array(list(df[df.columns[-1]]))
print(last_col)
print(last_col.shape)
```

**Results:**

```
[[ 2  4]
 [ 6  8]
 [10 12]]

(3, 2)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I can access the column the question is about the shape  that I get while reading them !

Comment: Well clearly I did not understand your question...  Suggest you try creating an MCVE....

Comment: Sorry the code that I have is just too big for the question, and I'm not sure how to could I make the problem clearer !